# QML How to open new page onClick with a Loader

Tags: qt, qml

I have an app that consists of multiple plages. And user will be able to switch between these pages by button clicks. When I put a Window {} in Kontrolpage.qml, it gives me EGLFS: OpenGL windows cannot be mixed with others error. So I put an Item in Kontrolpage.qml. In that way when I press the button, item gets opened. However, it looks small. Eventhough I set the size constraints in Kontrolpage.qml to 640-480 which is same as the size of the main.qml. So main qml still visible in the background and on top of it newly opened qml is visible but it's not fullscreen. How can I fix that thing and what I am doing wrong?

```
Window {
id:main
width:640
height:480

Image
{
   objectName: "background"
   width: parent.width
  height: parent.height
  source:"Imgs/Images/bckgnd.png"

LeftButtons
{
   id:buttonKontrol
   x: -20
   y:110 
   buttonName: "kontrol"

Loader { id: kontrolPageLoader}

MultiPointTouchArea
{
   id:touchArea_kontrol
   anchors.fill:parent
   onPressed:
   {
      kontrolPageLoader.source ="KontrolPage.qml"
}
}
}
}
```

And here is the Kontrolpage.qml:

```
Item{
visible:true
width:640
height:480

Image {
objectName:"background"
width:parent.width
height:parent.height
source:"Imgs/Images/bckgnd"
}
}
```

Edit: When I put Loader outside of the LeftButtons and into window {} as :

```
 Window {
    id:main
    width:640
    height:480
    
    Loader { id: kontrolPageLoader}

    Image
    {
       objectName: "background"
       width: parent.width
      height: parent.height
      source:"Imgs/Images/bckgnd.png"
    
    LeftButtons
    {
       id:buttonKontrol
       x: -20
       y:110 
       buttonName: "kontrol"
    
    
    
    MultiPointTouchArea
    {
       id:touchArea_kontrol
       anchors.fill:parent
       onPressed:
       {
          kontrolPageLoader.source ="KontrolPage.qml"
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

It does not open the new page. And keeping the loader inside the LeftButtons, when I use anchors.fill:parent, it resize it according to parent LeftButtons. However, I want to have the size of my Window in the new Page. The main problem in here looks like, why I cannot put Loader out of Leftbuttons and in Window?

Complete code for main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11



Window {
    id:main
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    //Constant Definitions

    readonly property string textColorBlue: "#8ccae5"
    readonly property string textColorRed: "#dc0000"


    Item {
        id: backgroundItem
        width:main.width
        height:main.height

        Loader
        {
            id:pageLoader
            anchors.fill:parent

        }

    Image
    {
        id:backgroundImage
        objectName: "background"
        width:parent.width
        height:parent.height
        source: "Imgs/Images/NMS_NEW_4_TR_03.png"






        LeftButtons
        {
            id: buttonKontrol
            x: -20
            y: 110
            buttonName:"Kontrol"




            MultiPointTouchArea
            {
                id:touchArea_kontrol
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed:
                {
                    buttonKontrol.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_left_red.png"
                    buttonKontrol.buttonTextColor=textColorRed
                    pageLoader.source="KontrolPage.qml"

                }
                onReleased:
                {
                    buttonKontrol.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_left_blue.png"
                    buttonKontrol.buttonTextColor=textColorBlue


                }
        }
        }

        LeftButtons
        {
            id:buttonKullaniciKitabi
            x:-20
            y:310
            buttonName:"Kullanıcı Kitabı"

            MultiPointTouchArea
            {
                id:touchArea_kullaniciKitabi
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed:
                {
                    buttonKullaniciKitabi.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_left_red.png"
                    buttonKullaniciKitabi.buttonTextColor=textColorRed
                }
                onReleased:
                {
                    buttonKullaniciKitabi.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_left_blue.png"
                    buttonKullaniciKitabi.buttonTextColor=textColorBlue
                }
        }
        }

        LeftButtons
        {
            id: buttonAyarlar
            x:-20
            y:510
            buttonName: "Ayarlar"

            MultiPointTouchArea
            {
                id:touchArea_ayarlar
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed:
                {
                    buttonAyarlar.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_left_red.png"
                    buttonAyarlar.buttonTextColor=textColorRed
                }
                onReleased:
                {
                    buttonAyarlar.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_left_blue.png"
                    buttonAyarlar.buttonTextColor=textColorBlue
                }
        }
        }

        RightButtons
        {
            id:buttonCCTV
            x:1050
            y:110
            buttonName: "CCTV"

            MultiPointTouchArea
            {
                id:touchArea_CCTV
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed:
                {
                    buttonCCTV.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_right_red.png"
                    buttonCCTV.buttonTextColor=textColorRed
                }
                onReleased:
                {
                    buttonCCTV.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_right_blue.png"
                    buttonCCTV.buttonTextColor=textColorBlue
                }
            }
        }

        RightButtons
        {
            id:buttonCTIS
            x:1050
            y:310
            buttonName: "CTIS"

            MultiPointTouchArea
            {
                id:touchArea_CTIS
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed:
                {
                    buttonCTIS.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_right_red.png"
                    buttonCTIS.buttonTextColor=textColorRed
                }
                onReleased:
                {
                    buttonCTIS.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_right_blue.png"
                    buttonCTIS.buttonTextColor=textColorBlue
                }
            }
        }

        RightButtons
        {
            id:buttonSisHavani
            x:1050
            y:510
            buttonName: "Sis Havanı"

            MultiPointTouchArea
            {
                id:touchArea_sisHavani
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed:
                {
                    buttonSisHavani.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_right_red.png"
                    buttonSisHavani.buttonTextColor=textColorRed
                }
                onReleased:
                {
                    buttonSisHavani.buttonImageColor="Imgs/Images/button_right_blue.png"
                    buttonSisHavani.buttonTextColor=textColorBlue
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: you should be setting the `Loader` width/height, or use `anchors.fill: parent` (the Item inside will have the same properties set)

Comment: Thanks, using anchors.fill:parent resizes the new page according to Leftbuttons size. But I want to have the size of the Window. And putting Loader out of Leftbuttons and in Window does not really work. ( I Edited the question with code.) Why the new way does not really work?

Comment: Window is not an item. Make covering Item in Window with 'width =main.width; height= main.height; id: backgroundItem'. Then you can use anchors.fill:backgroundItem

Comment: It doesn't really work because `Window` works with a contentItem, so the `LeftButton` becomes the contentItem if it's on it's own, and the contentItem does get set to fill the `Window`, and subsequently the Loader is set accordingly

Comment: @Nikxp Thanks, now I have a covering Item over Loader and Leftbutton. However, it gives QML LOader: Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling.

Comment: @Amfasis Actually I have more than 1 LefButton's, so I have more than one contentItem. Then how can I manage more than 1 contentItems (in my case LeftButtons) with only 1 Loader?

Comment: There is only one `contentItem` in `Window`, so the covering `Item` is the way to go. Is the `Loader` a direct child of the `Item` or nested within `LeftButton` (which is probably not a good idea)?

Comment: @Amfasis I didn't add the compete code for make it more readable (Now I edited the question and added the whole code). So in the whole code actually there are 3 LeftButtons and 3 RightButtons and they all will open a seperate window. I want to use only 1 Loader for that. Actually I use both, loader as direct child of Item or nested within LeftButton. It's same, still small window gets opened.